# asp.net mvc inject js code into Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How I can do it?

```
$for (var i = 0; i < model.CategoryList.length; i++) {
   var text = model.CategoryList;
   categories += '<span class="label label-info">' + @((AgesCategory)int.Parse( ..... )).GetDescription() + '</span>';
 }
```

I need replace **int.Parse( ..... ))** to **int.Parse(model.CategoryList[i])** from JS code. I can't add **text** variable into **int.Parse( ... )** intellisense detected this code like c# code, not JS.

**update:**

I'll try reformulate my question: How I can set value C# variable from JS variable?

```
<script>
    var temp1 = 1;   // js var
    @{ string temp2 = 0 ;}  // c# var
    @{ temp2 = temp1 } // how do it?
    var temp2 = @(((MyEnumType)int.Parse(temp2).GetEnumDescription()));  //js var
</script>
```

what need use? '@:' or something else? In all case I get syntax error

Comment: Could you clarify what is the problem or the error thrown. Moreover, explain what you want to achieve and what you did.

Comment: I can't add **text** variable into **int.Parse( ... )** intellisense detected this code like c# code, not JS.

Comment: Please edit your own post to add this information. You can do it with the Edit link at the bottom of your question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its possible. Because javascript execute at runtime, C# is compiled, it don't know the values for a runtime javascript so will be error.

You can have some study on "dynamic" types in C#, this is used in runtime.

But sorry, I am not able to write a demo here because I haven't much expirences on "dynamic" though I know it can do cross language things on C#. I can only give you this suggession.

Answer (score 0):

Understand that you can use @ expressions inside the <script> blocks within your views.  If you do so, some developer tools might not show code coloring or Intellisense for the JavaScript code block, but that won't impair the ability of the site to compile and be run.

HTH,
Clay

Comment: I'll try reformulate my question: How I can set value C# variable from JS variable?